# why do Google apps have TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD in non-password input fields

Tags: android, autofill, android-autofill-manager

My app is providing an Android Oreo Auto-fill service. It tries to detect potential credential forms, either by using the Autofill hints, or if these are not present (which is the case for most current apps), by other heuristics.

The main heuristic is to detect password fields, which I currently do by checking the `InputType` returned by `getInputType()`, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/assist/AssistStructure.ViewNode.html#getInputType()

Now users have reported that my app tries to fill the translation field of the Google translate app (which I can reproduce when I set the origin language to English) and even the phone dialer (which I can reproduce on a Google Pixel phone with Android 8.1.0). In both cases, the InputType has the flag `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` set. However, none of these fields is displayed as a password (with asterisks), so I wonder if my understanding of this input type is incorrect? Why would Google add this flag to the input type? How should I check for "is this a password field"?

Answer (score 0):

The View's *inputType* is independent of the view's *autofillHints* - you can use it to help on your heuristics, but you cannot assume that every field that has an *inputType* of password variation has the logical meaning of being a password.